# Use php to post and extract

Tags: php, post, curl, extract

I am really new to php, and this is what I am trying to do.

I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="something.com/get.php">

<tr height="5">
<td valign="top" style='font-family:verdana;font-size:8pt;'><br/>
<br/>Number: <br/>
<input type="text" name="number" size="20" maxlength="100" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> 

</form>
```

Now the get.php is located on some other sever

After sending the post data I get something like this on "get.php"

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="400">

<tr>
        <td>33721</td>
</tr>
```

Now my question and problem is I don't want to reveal the location of get.php.

So since I am new to php or any type of web programing, I am not sure how to do this.

What I had in mind was if I could make a php file which will get the post data from.

My form then pass it to the main page and then extract the contains from main page.

And display it to the user, I tried bunch of stuff like header and curl.

But non really worked probably because I am new, now I can't make any changes to the main page which is "get.php", so I have to find a another solution.

Comment: AJAX is your friend for this one. or if you like it hardcore then htaccess is also a good choice.

Comment: You're on the right track: create a page on your server which takes the form data, and have that page do a curl request to `something.com/get.php`.  Post the code that you tried.  Also, I don't see how AJAX or .htaccess will help with what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jnylen thanks for the help bro, I was able to use curl to do the job, And it turns out that i had curl install but was not showing up in phpinfo, Took me some time to reinstall it but fix it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you need to use Apache's mod_rewrite to rewrite the url to something else.

So you could then hide the location of the script by having the url your form submits to as something like:

something.com/get

which could then be rewritten by mod_rewrite, something like this:

RewriteRule ^/get$ /path-to-script/get.php

This way you can put the script anywhere. You could then deny access to the script via the url. So if someone tries to access get.php directly they will get a forbidden error message from apache.

So altogether in your vhost you would have something like the following:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/get$ /path-to-script/get.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/path-to-script/get.php - [F,NS]

What this effectively does is say rewrite url's of the form '/get' to /path-to-script/get.php and if someone tries to access /path-to-script/get.php directly (through the address bar), forbid it.

This way you can put get.php somewhere that is not obvious and also stop people from accessing it.

I realise this may be quite complicated if as you say you are new, but it something you may want to look into.

Comment: Well curl fixed my problem, But i never thought of using something like that, I am going to try this too, Thanks :)